# Struts2 ActionContext setName method not working

Tags: java, struts2, servlet-filters, interceptor

I am trying to write a interceptor in Struts2  which redirects request to different action based on some condition. My interceptor works fine which is as given below.

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
        ActionContext actionContext=actionInvocation.getInvocationContext();
        String actionName=actionContext.getName();
        String actionResult=null;
        if(actionName.equals("admin"))
        {
            System.out.println("admin");
            //if(based on some condition)
            actionContext.setName("ErrorPageForLinkAccess");
                    System.out.println(actionContext.getName());
        }
        actionResult = actionInvocation.invoke();   
        return  actionResult;
    }
```

Struts  configuration

```
<action name="other">
<result>Jsp/other.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="admin" class="com.example.Admin" method="adminDemo">
<result name="success">Jsp/admin.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="ErrorPageForLinkAccess">
    <result name="success">Jsp/ErrorPageForLinkAccess.jsp</result>
</action>
```

When ever i call admin action, console output

```
admin
ErrorPageForLinkAccess
```

But still its not calling the action `ErrorPageForLinkAccess` rather calling `admin` action.
Why i am facing this problem?

Comment: Setting the name won't change which action is executed. Instead return some different result from interceptor and configure this result in struts.xml.

Comment: What are you trying to set useless until you not override the default behavior Struts will set the action name to you.

Comment: @Aleksandr your suggestion is good, But my requirement is different.I wanted to call diffeerent action not just returning result. Because i need to configure result name for each action.

Comment: @Roman you may be correct, i need to find some solution

Comment: You can configure global result for that.

Comment: What's even the point of doing it like this? Configure an interceptor for this action only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this problem because the action is already resolved and invoked by the dispatcher, so changing the action name in the action context is useless. Struts has done this in filter

```
ActionMapping mapping = prepare.findActionMapping(request, response, true);
if (mapping == null) {
    boolean handled = execute.executeStaticResourceRequest(request, response);
    if (!handled) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
} else {
    execute.executeAction(request, response, mapping);
}
```

Comment: Then why they providing setName()

Comment: @mahesh It's a setter to set the `name` to the bean. And Struts doesn't care how you will use it.